# VBScript to exe

Tags: vbscript

I have written a code to create a new menu in MS Word and do some functions. I have written VBScript code in the scripting window which opens when i do Alt+F11.

I cannot send the code to the customer and have to bundle it in an exe file or some other file and send  it to user.

How do i do that.

If i create an exe file when the user runs it the menu button should be cretaed in MS Word on users machine.

Thanks
Creator

Answer (score 0):

The simplest options are:

1. Add the VB**A** to the normal template and you can make it [run when Word loads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208800%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to add your menu items.
2. [Create an add-in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140953%28v=office.10%29.aspx) from the macro project (These can be read only/password protected)
3. Create a [managed/VSTO add-in](http://dave.thielen.com/articles/Word%20Add-In%20Part%200.htm)